# How to get "duplicates list edited" history from the public data dump or SEDE?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, data-explorer, data-dump

I want to search questions whose duplicates list has been edited. Take [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7558022/timeline) as an example:

[image: Timeline of the question]

The timeline shows that the type of "duplicates list edited" is **history**, but the list edit history can not be found in the public data dump, nor in SEDE.

My simple query code in SEDE:

```
SELECT *
FROM posthistory as ph
where ph.PostId = 7558022
```

The result does not contain "duplicates list edited":

[image: result of query]

So how can I get the "duplicates list edited" history?

Comment: It's really interesting the Dupe List Edit event is either apparently not stored as a PostHistory event, or purged from the dataset. I'd probably lean towards the former as the cause, but I'd love to here an official explanation.

Answer (score 8):

This information does not seem to be included in SEDE. However, if all you want is

> to search questions whose duplicates list has been edited

then [the following stub](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1395399) may help you. The `PostLinks` table contains information about the current duplicate(s), while the most recent `PostHistory` entry with type `10` contains the initial duplicate list. (It can be a list if users provided different duplicate targets during the initial closure.)

Comment: I still slightly confused why the history "duplicates list edited" is an exception. Hope it will be included in later versions. Thanks a lot for your Answer!